# Push Notification does not work with HTTP and POST method using Java and Cordova-Phonegap

Tags: java, cordova, firebase, push-notification

I am working with firebase and notificacion push messages for mobile devices. I configured the firebase console with one project and two applications (IOS - ANDROID). If I try to sent a notification using firebase console, the message is visible on the device, but if I use http protocol and POST method, the response is code 200 with this message: {"multicast_id":******,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}. And I Don't know how to find the error about invalid registration because the message does not sent to phone. I copied the SERVER_KEY and the TOKENs for the apps and I setted this from server:

```
String title = "TITLE";

String message = "THIS IS A MESSAGE";

String APP_ID[] = {
               "1:********:ios:*******",
               "1:*******:android:*****"
};

String SERVER_KEY="***************....****";

String SERVER_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

String json = "{"
        + "\"notification\":{"
        + "\"title\": \""+title+"\","
        + "\"body\": \""+message+"\","
        + "\"sound\": \"default\""
        + "},"
        + "\"content_available\": true,"
        + "\"priority\": \"high\","
        + "\"to\": \""+APP_ID[1]+"\""
        + "}";

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVER_URL);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "key="+SERVER_KEY);
request.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())+". Status Code: "+responseCode);

client.close();
```

In mobile device the configuration is on Javascript using phonegap-plugin-push. When I run the Cordova APP, the console shows successfull registration. 
google-services.json and GoogleServices-info.plist were configured during installation plugin using the command:

```
$> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID = 'SENDER_CODE_extract_from_firebase_project'
```

And javascript configuration:

```
var app = {
 bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
 },
 onDeviceReady: function() {
   app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        PushNotification.hasPermission(permissionListener);

        var push = PushNotification.init({
                        android: {
                            vibrate: true,
                            sound: true
                        },
                        ios: {
                            alert: true,
                            sound: true
                        }
                    });

        push.on('error',errorListener);

        push.on('registration',registrationListener);

        push.on('notification', notificationListener);

    }
};



 //FOR PUSH NOTIFICATIONS

    /**
     * Listen if the device has permissions.
     */ 
    function permissionListener(data) {

        console.log('is enabled: '+data.isEnabled);

    }

    /**
     * For registration event
     */ 
    function registrationListener(data){
        console.log("Registration id: "+data.registrationId);
        console.log("Registration Type: "+data.registrationType);
    }


    function notificationListener(data){
            alert(data.message);
    }

    function errorListener(e){
        console.log("ERROR with PUSH NOTIFICATIONS: "+e.message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending wrong deviceId received by the phone to the server,make sure deviceId  should not change or modify.

> Invalid Registration 
>   Token 200 + 
>   error:InvalidRegistration Check the
>   format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it
>   matches the registration token the client app receives from
>   registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add
>   additional characters.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Answer (score 0):

Well, my issue was fixed changing the "APPS_ID" vector values. I was confused for the ids on the field "to" on JSON. the  APP ID is not the correct token to send messages.
When I run the app cordova, the plugin for push notifications shows a registration ID, and that is the correct token.